# Help understanding a proof about vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The exercise goes like this:

-Let $W= {(x,y,z)|2x+3y-z=0}$ Then $W\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3$, find the dimension of $W$.

-Find the dimension $[\mathbb{R}^3|W]$

This was a problem from my algebra exam, it was a team exam and this problem was solved by another member of the team (we...he had it right), his solution goes like this:

Lets take the natural projection of $\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3|W$, we have $Dim \,\,\mathbb{R}^3=3$, $\text{dim}\,\, Ker= dim \,W=2$.
because it is superyective by the dimension theorem we have dim $[\mathbb{R}^3|W]=1$

I don't understand the solution (I think he used things we haven't seen in class, he's a little bit ahead). I can see why Dim $\mathbb{R}^3=3$ but not why dim $Ker= dim\, W=2$ and why dim $[\mathbb{R}^3|W]=1$. What does being superyective have to do with it?

Can someone please explain what is used here? We already got an A in the exam but I'd like to understand how the problem was solved.

I know it's probably something very basic, but I don't know much.

Thanks

Comment: I assume $\text{Sub}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ means "a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$"? I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: yes, that's what it means (how is it usually written?)

Answer (score 1):

To show $W$ is a subspace, use the Subspace Theorem: $0\in W$, $W$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

To compute the dimension of $W$, just note that $2x+3y-z=0$ implies $x=-3y+z$. So you have two free variables: $y$ and $z$. Thus, $W$ is two dimensional.

Since $\mathbb{R}^3$ is three dimensional and $W$ is two dimensional, then $\mathbb{R}^3/W$ is one dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

I think an easy way to solve this is as follows:

dim $(\mathbb R^3)/W$=dim $\mathbb R^3$-dim $W$

Now let $(a,b,c)\in W$ then $2a+3b-c=0$
so $c=2a+3b$

so a basis  for $W$ is $\{(1,0,2)^t,(0,1,3)^t\}$ so dim$W$=2

So you get your answer.

Another way out is try the linear mapping $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R$
defined by $f(x,y,z)=2x+3y-z$(check it's linear) having kernel as $W$.Then $\mathbb R^3/W\cong Imf$ .Im$f$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ having dimension $1$

Comment: "Then R^3/W≅Imf" Why?

Comment: this is called the fundamental theorem for homomorphism of vector spaces

Comment: U can try this map if u are not sure $\phi:V/K\rightarrow T(V)$ defined by $\phi(K+x)=T(x)$ where $K=ker T$ and $T$ is a linear map from $V$ to $U$